# jQuery replacewith

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, replace

I was wondering if it is possible to replace a part of a string with variable.

basically what I want to do is the following
I want to replace [socialnetworks] with the social network code.

the way it gets the code is via $.POST as it has to fetch this from the mysql database via PHP

Comment: What do you mean by "replacing with variable"?

Comment: Baisclly I want to replace it with HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var code = "<p>Something</p>";
yourString.replace("[socialnetworks]", code);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

I don't know if it's what you wanted ;).

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

```
$("*").each(function () { 
if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace('[socialnetworks]',variable)); 
   } 
});
```